# Iterating over a list for a set number of times in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible, trying to achieve following:
Store the output in an array,and iterate over the array " COUNT" times, where count is total number of elements minus one in the array/list.

Below is my example playbook.

```
  ---
    - name: GETTING INTERFACES
      connection: network_cli
      cli_command:
        command: show  interfaces terse | match ge-
      register: A

    - name: LISTING CONTENTS of LIST
      debug:
        var: A.stdout_lines


    - name: COUNTING ELEMENTS
      set_fact:
        COUNT: "{{ (A.stdout_lines|length)-1 }}"


    - name: DISPLAY
      debug:
        var: COUNT


    - name: ITERATING OVER LIST 
      debug: var=item
      loop: MUST LOOP OVER THE LIST "COUNT" TIMES How can I achieve this?

Thanks and have a good weekend!!
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can you replace the final `debug` task with a task that demonstrates your goal? There might be a different way to accomplish what you want, but there's not enough information here to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,  I am trying to learn how to iterate over an array, I do not have specific task, just trying to learn this technique so I can use it when there is a need,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"Iterate over the array COUNT times, where COUNT is the total number of elements in the array minus one."*

A: It's possible to use [nested](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/nested.html#nested-composes-a-list-with-nested-elements-of-other-lists). The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    A:
      stdout_lines:
        - line1
        - line2
        - line3

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ query('sequence', params) }}"
        - "{{ A.stdout_lines }}"
      vars:
        count: "{{ A.stdout_lines|length - 2 }}"
        params: "{{ 'start=0 end=' ~ count }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml | grep msg\":
    "msg": "0 line1"
    "msg": "0 line2"
    "msg": "0 line3"
    "msg": "1 line1"
    "msg": "1 line2"
    "msg": "1 line3"
```